# Сообщения в логи о присоединении не приходят

Tags: python, discord.py

```
#If user connect your discord server
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='ds_user')
    emb = discord.Embed(title='Новый пользователь',colour=discord.Colour.purple())
    emb.add_field(name='Присоединился', value=member.mention)
    emb.set_author(name=member.name,url=member.avatar_url)
    emb.set_footer(text=f'User ID: {member.id}')
    await channel.send(embed=emb)

#If users disconnect your discord server
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='ds_user')
    emb = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.purple(), title='Пользователь ушел')
    emb.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    emb.add_field(
        name='Ушел ;(', 
        value=member.mention
        )
    emb.set_footer(
        text=f'User ID: {member.id}'
        )
    await channel.send(embed=emb)
```

Comment: Если что это discord python

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь получать channel используя ID канала:

```
channel = bot.get_channel(АЙДИ_КАНАЛА_Без_КАВЫЧЕК)
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

уважаемый участник! Вы забыли получить канал, в который нужно добавить. Сейчас я попытаюсь вам поправить данную проблему. Давайте я возьму кусочек вашего кода.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='ds_user')
```

Для начала уточним то, что можно сделать отправку в канал через два способа.
Первый: `channel = bot.get_channel(ChannelId)`, а второй `await ctx.bot.get_channel(ChannelId).send('Text')`.

Давайте используем оба способа на моем примере:

```py
@bot.command() # Создаем команду
async def send(ctx, channelid): # Добавляем аргумент "channelid", т.е. куда будет отправлять наше сообщение
   await ctx.bot.get_channel(int(channelid)).send('Пример!') # Переводим "channelid" в цифры, затем отправляем
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
@bot.command()
async def send(ctx):
   channel = bot.get_channel(923633779627675691) # Вставьте свой канал туда
   await channel.send('Пример!')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь, я вам очень помог! Приятного дня, мур~